# Remove doubles corrupts vertex groups

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

When I use 'Remove doubles' on my weight painted mesh it will mess up the vertex group selection:

Before doubles removed:

[image]

After:

[image]

Somebody knows a solution for this ?

Comment: "*Somebody knows a solution for this?*" Yes, redefine your vertex groups. Vertex were eliminated by removing doubles, you can't possibly expect vertex groups to remain untouched.

Comment: Is there any wax to select a vertex group with the invisible vertices (what is wasn't applied to te vertex group) automatically ? so I can fix the whole thing